# Error in Next JS REACT: Objects are not valid as a React child. Just want to use dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, date-formatting

I want to convert this { passagens.departure_date } into date like 1 nov, 2 dez examples. This { passagens.departure_date } is like this value: 2022-10-02T00:00:00Z. I just want to pick the right date in strings.

I Try everything. This is my code Also i did the function pegaDia

```
export function pegaDia(str) {
  var monthNames = [
    "Jan",
    "Fev",
    "Mar",
    "Abr",
    "Mai",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Ago",
    "Set",
    "Out",
    "Nov",
    "Dez",
  ];

  var d = new Date(str); //converts the string into date object
  var m = d.getMonth(); //get the value of month
  var n = monthNames[m];
  var dia = d.getDate() + 1;
  return { dia, n };
}
```

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import api from "../../services/api";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { pegaDia } from "./functions";

export default function Board() {
  const [passagens, setPassagens] = useState([] as any);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadPassagens() {
      const response = await api.get("ZLIMIT_1?limit=10");
      //console.log(response.data.slice(0, 10));
      setPassagens(response.data.slice(0, 10));
    }
    loadPassagens();
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Passagens Promocionais</title>
      </Head>

      <div className={styles.container}>
        
        <div className={styles.listapassagens}>
          {passagens.map((passagens) => {
            return (
              <article key={passagens.created}>
                <strong>{passagens.arrival_ap_city}</strong>
                <br /> <span>Saindo de: {passagens.departure_ap_city}</span>
                **<span>Ida ${pegaDia("{ passagens.departure_date }")}</span>**
                <span>Volta {passagens.returning_date}</span>
                <span>Preço {passagens.price_w_fees}</span>
              </article>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: `pegaDia()` returns an object with `dia` and `n` properties. Is there anything unclear in the error message?

Comment: JavaScript dates are objects. You'll need to convert it to a string format, either manually or using a library like Moment or Date-Fns.

Comment: Sorry for that
it is showing an error, not working. I'm still a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you want something like this...

First, create a date formatter for your locale (or a specific one if you want)

```js
const locale = undefined; // leave undefined to use the current locale
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
  day: "numeric",
  month: "short",
});
```

Then use it to format your dates

```jsx
<span>Ida {formatter.format(new Date(passagens.departure_date))}</span>
```

---

You could automatically parse the date strings when setting your data to avoid calling `new Date()` every render

```js
setPassagens(response.data.slice(0, 10).map(({ departure_date, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  departure_date: new Date(departure_date),
}));
```